# Problem validators langage use when there is a decimal field in a form for an abp modal

Tags: c#, jquery, forms, customvalidator, abp

## Describe the bug

With a model that contains a `decimal` property, this doesn't work with a locale that uses a decimal comma:

```
<input asp-for="Number">
<input asp-for="Number" type="number">
```

Code:
I am used a modal for display my form and a ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel 
{
           [StringLength(56)]
           public string Speciality { get; set; }

           [StringLength(128)]
           public string StructureLinked { get; set; }

           [Required]
           [AbpRadioButton(Inline = true)]
           public RateType RateSelected { get; set; }

           [HiddenInput]
           public decimal RateGeneral { get; set; }

           public decimal RateSpecific { get; set; }
}
```

The first issue is that the rest of the form return french validator langage as expected, but for all the properties which use `decimal` the validator is in English.
The second issues is that we give a data without comma it's send and receive correctly. But if we respect the `English format` as `9.8`  we receive `0`.

I tried to force the loading of the file jqueryvalidator/message_fr.js or some differents fix find on web without success